# Stop bootstrap-select dropdown menu from moving other controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a form that looks like the following when closed and when opened:

[image: Closed Dropdown]

[image: Open Dropdown]

The save button is moving.  I've replicated the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/m06eob4h/1/ with following markup.

I'm using snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select (without any custom styling) and bootstrap 4.  Here is what I think the relevant rendered markup looks like:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="card-columns">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Plan 1 Status</h5>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col-sm-6 field-edit">
        <div class="viAuthStatus1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="iAuthStatus1">
              <span class="liAuthStatus1">Election Status</span>
            </label>
            <div class="validator-container">
              <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control iAuthStatus1">
                <select name="iAuthStatus1" id="iAuthStatus1" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick iAuthStatus1">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="Pend">Pending Review</option>
                  <option value="Rev">In Review</option>
                  <option value="Wa">Waiting</option>
                  <option value="Com">Package Complete</option>
                  <option value="DECL">Decline</option>
                  <option value="INC">Incomplete</option>
                  <option value="Inelig">Ineligible</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Plan 1 Status</h5>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col-sm-6 field-edit">
        <div class="viAuthStatus1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="iAuthStatus1">
              <span class="liAuthStatus1">Election Status</span>
            </label>
            <div class="validator-container">
              <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control iAuthStatus1">
                <select name="iAuthStatus1" id="iAuthStatus1" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick iAuthStatus1">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="Pend">Pending Review</option>
                  <option value="Rev">In Review</option>
                  <option value="Wa">Waiting</option>
                  <option value="Com">Package Complete</option>
                  <option value="DECL">Decline</option>
                  <option value="INC">Incomplete</option>
                  <option value="Inelig">Ineligible</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="align-items-end">
<a class="btn btn-primary SaveEdits mr-1" href="javascript:alert('hi');">Save</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, you'll see that my fiddle has two issues when I expand the dropdown in the first card.

1) The Save button moves down.

2) The second card moves around.

**UPDATE** - I've modified the html to have two cards (more like our real app) and the associated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your HTML (6th line):

```
<div class="row align--end">
                      ^
                      X
```

shouldn't it be

```
 <div class="row align-items-end">
```

maybe thats causing this issue
**Edit** So this code works on my machines (did a quick test on win/MacOS with FF74 and Chrome > 79) as it should

```
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Plan 1 Status</h5>
            <div class="row align-items-end">
              <div class="col-sm-6 field-edit">
                <div id="ControlHost_ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status_iAuthStatus1" class="viAuthStatus1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="iAuthStatus1">
                      <span class="liAuthStatus1">Election Status</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="validator-container">
                      <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control iAuthStatus1">
                        <select name="ControlHost:ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status:iAuthStatus1:iAuthStatus1" id="ControlHost_ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status_iAuthStatus1_iAuthStatus1" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick iAuthStatus1" data-size="15" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="Pend">Pending Review</option>
                          <option value="Rev">In Review</option>
                          <option value="Wa">Waiting</option>
                          <option value="Com">Package Complete</option>
                          <option value="DECL">Decline</option>
                          <option value="INC">Incomplete</option>
                          <option value="Inelig">Ineligible</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <!-- /div -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary SaveEdits mr-1" href="javascript:alert('hi');">Save</a>
    </div>
```

So I placed the button inside the card - works (commented div). If you put the save button out of the card but inside the card-column than it moves around like drunk when changing screen sizes 
This solution puts it out of the card column in an extra row (which you could also skip) - that works too like expected:

```
    <div class="card-columns col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Plan 1 Status</h5>
            <div class="row align-items-end">
              <div class="col-sm-6 field-edit">
                <div id="ControlHost_ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status_iAuthStatus1" class="viAuthStatus1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="iAuthStatus1">
                      <span class="liAuthStatus1">Election Status</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="validator-container">
                      <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control iAuthStatus1">
                        <select name="ControlHost:ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status:iAuthStatus1:iAuthStatus1" id="ControlHost_ParticipantTab-Paper-Elections-Document-Status_iAuthStatus1_iAuthStatus1" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick iAuthStatus1" data-size="15" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="Pend">Pending Review</option>
                          <option value="Rev">In Review</option>
                          <option value="Wa">Waiting</option>
                          <option value="Com">Package Complete</option>
                          <option value="DECL">Decline</option>
                          <option value="INC">Incomplete</option>
                          <option value="Inelig">Ineligible</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="px-2 align-items-end"><!-- px-1 to px-3 to add different indents -->
      <a class="btn btn-primary SaveEdits mr-1" href="javascript:alert('hi');">Save</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it should have been align-items-end.  Eagle eyes ;)  But that was just me messing around in Chrome debugger removing styles to see if it fixed the problem and I didn't restore it before I copied.  So, that didn't fix my 'real' problem, nor did it clean up my fiddle, but I've updated the question and the fiddle.

Comment: See my edit basicly two easy choices - button in side card or button outside card.column, more complex solutions might be possible but...

Comment: I did your second option (the first isn't possible b/c in our app we have multiple cards rendered on the page but only want one submit).  Anyway, here is fiddle, but it seems like Save button isn't below the card like I'd like.  http://jsfiddle.net/xrn3pywd/

Comment: As I wrote delete the row (like I wrote you could skip) from <div class="row align-items-end"> then its exactly on the left edge or put it into an approptiate class to get indents. px-1 up to px-3 whatever you prefer I'll edit above

Comment: OK, got it setup as you wanted I think.  http://jsfiddle.net/m06eob4h/  Initially, the save does appear below, so that's good.  But now back to the original problem, when you drop down the select, the save moves (and not even the extra card - which I added to simulate what our UI would really look like - moves).

Comment: What browser are you using on both of my machines your fiddle works asexpected

Comment: I am using Chrome.  FF seems to behave, but Chrome, IE, and Edge all 'move' the button and second card.  What are you testing in?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer  win/MacOS with FF74 and Chrome > 79) this is a test fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8sbnhpg/ I did all kind of things the button stays where it should

Comment: You didn't use bootstrap-select.  I added those resources to your fiddle, then the button moves.  http://jsfiddle.net/vmy8jkf4/  So it is something to do with bootstrap-select obviously.  Just having a hard time figuring out what css style or whatever to override to make it work better.